# In .NET, when setting an XmlElement's InnerText property, how come ampersands get encoded but apostrophes don't?

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following example code:

```
public static XmlElement CreateElement(XmlDocument doc, string innerText)
{
    XmlElement el = doc.CreateElement("name");
    el.InnerText = innerText;

    return el;
}
```

When called like this, I get `&amp;` in place of the original `&` in the OuterText property as expected:

```
XmlElement myElement = CreateElement(myDoc, "Alice & Bob");
// myElement.OuterText has "<name>Alice &amp; Bob</name>"
```

But, when I call it like the below, where I would expect to have a `&apos;` I simply have the actual `'`:

```
XmlElement myElement = CreateElement(myDoc, "Alice's Bob");
// myElement.OuterText has "<name>Alice's Bob</name>"
```

Does anybody know the reason why the apostrophe wasn't encoded and is there a way to get it to be encoded in the OuterText?

Comment: Why should it be encoded? It's not a control character in element content. It can be interpreted as a control character in an attribute value, but the parser can recognise you're not in the attribute region and therefore never needs to interpret it that way.

Comment: It does not require encoding, it only has significance in an XML single quoted entity like an attribute value when that entity itself needs to contain a single quote.

Comment: I realise it's legal XML to have the apostrophe without encoding, but the spec for the XML I am producing requires apostrophes to be encoded (and it is data we are giving a third-party so I don't have a choice). Unfortunately, when I manually encode the apostrophes with `&apos;` they become `&amp;apos;` in the OuterText, which is an undesired effect. Is there any way to avoid encoding alltogether so that I can manually encode it?

Comment: Your out of luck with this API (and Xml.Linq) I think.  You can do it with `XmlWriter.WriteRaw("Alice&apos;s Bob"))` but you would need to use that exclusively because combining it with XmlElement will cause double/unescaping.  Perhaps the simplest thing is to simply let it produce `&amp;apos;` then as a last step conver the XML to a string and `.Replace("&amp;apos;", "&apos;");`

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Tom W and Alex K you don't need it to be encoded (as standard of the XmlElement transformation) but if you want to you can do this:

```
public static System.Xml.XmlElement CreateElement(System.Xml.XmlDocument doc, string innerText)
{
    System.Xml.XmlElement el = doc.CreateElement("name");
    el.InnerText = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(innerText);
    return el;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Sammuel, but encoding the inner text before assigning it means that all the ampersands will be re-encoded in the OuterText, so `&apos;` becomes `&amp;apos;` which is unwanted.